# Extract second subelement of every element in a list while ignoring NA's in sapply in R

Tags: r, list, apply, na, sapply

I'm trying to extract the second subelement of every element in a list while ignoring NAs in R.  Here's a small example:

```
mylist <- list(a=c(6,7),b=NA,c=c(8,9))
sapply(mylist, "[[", 1)
sapply(mylist, "[[", 2) #receive error
```

Because element 'b' has only one subelement (NA), I receive the following error when trying to extract the second subelement:

```
Error in FUN(X[[2L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
```

My goal is for the output to be: 7, NA, 9.  In other words, I want to **ignore and retain the NAs so that the output is the same length as the number of elements in the list**.  I would like the solution to be general enough to also be able to apply it to a different subelement, n, from each list.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
sapply(mylist,function(x) x[2])
```

Comment: Or more concisely, but equivalently, `sapply(mylist,\`[\`,2)
`

Answer (score 0):

If the list just contains double vectors as in the example, I suggest:

```
purrr::map_dbl(mylist, 2, .default=NA)
```

Otherwise:

```
library(dplyr); purrr::map(mylist, 2, .default=NA) %>% unlist()
```